# How to make a circular polygon pour in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, copper-pour

I have a circular PCB for an LED circuit and I want to cover the free space with polygon pour to enable larger current to pass thru the circuit. The Polygon pour option only permits polygon (with vertices) drawing of copper pour.

How can I draw a circular copper pour?
[image: Circular PCB Board]

Answer (score 2):

Run a keep-out around the edges of your PCB first. Then place a large enough rectangle copper pour containing the whole PCB. Set the net of the pour, adjust the clearances if necessary. Done.

Answer (score 1):

As Rohat suggested, keep-out primitives set by the shape of the board is the preferred way to do this.

But to answer the OPs question academically, circular polygons can be created by the following:

1. Draw a square polygon. It helps if the width and height are even multiples of the grid (e.g. 1mm grid, width and height 20mm)
2. Click-and-drag a corner vertex (Using SHIFT + Space to select Mitre to Arc) and release the vertex at half the height of the polygon. (e.g. Y minus 10mm)
3. Repeat for the other 3 corners.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]